# Disable Downloading the entire blockchain using Bitcoin core?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

I know bitcoin core by default downloads the entire blockchain, but is there a stripped down version that isn't 60+gb big? I need to be able to create addresses and label each one for specific usage such as savings, spending 1, spending 2, etc.

Comment: Note that you'll still have to download it completely, you just don't keep it completely after verifying. If you don't download and verify, you don't have full node security.

Comment: so i still need 100Gb of space initially to download it then I can delete it?

Comment: No, it'll prune already while you're synchronizing. Don't manually delete it, you'd have to synchronize from scratch again. Start with `-prune=<n>`.

Comment: is there a setting in the bitcoin core gui to just set this option without having to manually create a bitcoin.conf file? also i dont even know where it should go in a win10 / win7 computer.